# Insert child elements in d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, css-selectors

I am trying to create a table using D3.js, but td elements are not nesting inside the tr.

This is what I am trying to create:

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Value</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
    var myTable = d3.select("#myTable")

    var myTableRow = myTable.selectAll("tr")
        .data(myData);

    myTableRow.enter()
        .append("tr")
        .insert("td", ":first-child")
        .html(function(d) {
            return d.name;
        })
        .insert("td", ":first-child")
        .html(function(d) {
            return d.value;
        });
```

However, each td does not nest inside the tr.

Comment: Is there a CSS selector I could use to hit the tr, so that the second td is added inside the tr instead of inside the first td?

Comment: If you are looking to step UP the hierarchy that is not provided - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/mEjem7IPshY. There are other options you could try though - but a variable based method seems clearest.

Answer (score 7):

```
var myTable = d3.select("#myTable")

var myTableRow = myTable.selectAll("tr")
    .data(myData)
    .enter()
    .append("tr")

myTableRow.append("td", ":first-child")
    .html(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    })
myTableRow.append("td", ":first-child")
    .html(function (d) {
        return d.value;
    });
```

---

```js
var myData = [
  { name: 'a', value: 1 },
  { name: 'b', value: 2 },
]

var myTable = d3.select("#myTable")

var myTableRow = myTable.selectAll("tr")
        .data(myData)
        .enter()
        .append("tr")

myTableRow.append("td", ":first-child")
  .html(function (d) {
     return d.name;
  })
myTableRow.append("td", ":first-child")
  .html(function (d) {
     return d.value;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but when I try to add new data, elements get added twice.

Comment: How are you adding the new data?